# Is it possible to pull HTML code into a Sharepoint workflow email?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I've been asked to set up an email communications for our department, where we can click to send fully formatted html emails based on list entries out to other teams.  I'm having issues getting this to work properly, but as an interim solution, I'm wondering whether I can add a new field where users can paste the html text into and have a workflow pull from this field and output into the body of an email without showing it as plain text.

Currently, I've tried with a blank body apart from the one call to a rich text field I've called 'CommsHTML', however this outputs into the email as plain text, with all the coding elements showing.  I've tried copying the HTML directly into the workflow email's 'body' and that works without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's  possible. Per my test, we could pull HTML code into a sharepoint workflow email.

Below is my test:

1.Add a field "Html code"
[image]

2.In the workflow email, add this field.
[image]

3.The email I get like this:

[image]